# How do I get a blog post to show up in the site sidebar?

Tags: support, bug, blog

I have posted a short blog entry about a change to the site scope to announce the allowing of beta questions.

- http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2015/08/beta-ios-9-and-el-capitan-questions-allowed/

In the past, it would show up promptly in the sidebar / community bulletin area. So far, it's a no show.

[image: screen capture showing SE blog post, but not AD blog post]

Do I need to do something specific to allow that or has that been changed intentionally over time?

Comment: I suppose I could abuse the "community event" tool to do this, but would rather wait if it's something the code can handle natively once it's hooked up again. (??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up "abusing" the "community event" tool to promote the blog post for one week.

[image]

Other than the pedantic argument that it's not an event, it seems to be working well.